# How to use ng-grid in Hawtio?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, hawtio

I believe that `ng-grid` requires at least AngularJS 1.2.x.

I noticed that there is an `ng-grid` module in Hawtio. Is it possible to use this `ng-grid` module in Hawtio's current AngularJS version 1.1.5?

Can someone give an example how to use this? We tried but were getting errors, maybe due to version dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can use that, though we used ng-grid in the start with hawtio, but it has some issues (not all data was shown in all browsers etc) and was slow. And we needed a simple grid, so we wrote a simpletable we used instead.

But you should be able to use it,maybe search the source code of hawtio-web and find the few spots left where ng-grid may still be in use.